# ReactJS filter including an array list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 {nDATA
          .filter((newData) => newData.titles.includes(props.currentFilter))
          .map((value, index) => (
```

So in the code above I have `nDATA` which is an `array` of `objects` that I am filtering and mapping out.

Then I also have `props.currentFilter` which is a `prop` being passed into this component that is an `array` list for example

```
["Apples", "Oranges", "Strawberries", "Grapes"]
```

What I am trying to do here is get my filter setup here to check each `newData.titles` for each of the arrays in `props.currentFilter`. That way when I am searching for say `Apples` and `Oranges` and `Grapes`, it will check each thing for each of those and if it has 1 of them it goes through. My setup right now is working perfect if I pass just a string into the includes by doing `props.currentFilter[0]` but that does me no good for what I am trying to do here. I have been trying to test a few ways to do this and have been struggling to figure this out, any help would be much appreciated =D

Comment: Is `newData.titles` a string?

Comment: Yeah its a string

Comment: If it is a string then iamuchejude's answer should work... if it's an array then you can try: `.filter(newData => props.currentFilter.some(str => newData.titles.includes(str)))`

Comment: Ah maybe its an array then ill try that

Comment: Looks like it was an array lol. That worked perfect, post that as an answer and ill give ya checkmark. I appreciate your time greatly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in your filter method to check if *some* value from your `props.currentFilter` is included within your `newData.titles` array:

```
nDATA
  .filter(newData => props.currentFilter.some(str => newData.titles.includes(str)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nData.filter(newData => props.currentFilter.includes(newData.titles))
```

Comment: Does not seem to work but I am trying to see if maybe I can see why its not working lol. Also I fixed the nDATA so its not that. Its just coming back as no results

Answer (score 0):

An optimal way to run this function would be to turn your currentFilter array into an object with the keys being your filter words. Values can be anything.

```
let filterObj = props.currentFilter.reduce((acc, cur) => {
 acc[cur] = 1
 return acc
}, {})
```

which should return

```
filterObj = {
 "apples": 1,
 "oranges": 1,
 "bananas": 1,
}
```

Then run your filter loop and call hasOwnProperty method which returns a boolean

```
{nDATA
          .filter((newData) => currentFilter.hasOwnProperty(newData.titles))
          .map((value, index) => (
```

Comment: If you're using an object for the sole purpose of efficient look-up then you'd be better of using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for that :)

Comment: @NickParsons thanks for the tip! Do Sets and Objects in JS have different lookup runtimes?

Comment: They both should be the same, so you can expect O(1) for both `.has()` (on the set) and object lookup.